# Не могу подсчитать пример в python, получается неправильный ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу подсчитать пример в python, получается 0 в ответе.
вот сам пример: **pow(12814433311, 2) - 21299881*pow(2776584, 2)**

в с++ получается:

ответ = 385

```
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
 
    int128_t a = 12814433311ull * 12814433311ull;
    int128_t b = 21299881ull * 2776584ull * 2776584ull;
 
    int128_t c = a - b;
 
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `128144333112` != `12814433311` ;)

Comment: этот вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. он вызван опечаткой и не несет никакой пользы  сообществу SO

Comment: @MaxU да опечатка, но все равно, у меня почему то выходит 0

Comment: у меня получается 385

Comment: @MaxU убрал pow, заменил на ** получилось 385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в питоне получается

```
16256760407637153182208
```

в калькуляторе Windows:

```
16256760407637153182208
```

в вашем же кода

```
int128_t a = 12814433311ull * 12814433311ull;
```

а в описании вопроса

```
pow(128144333112, 2) - 21299881*pow(2776584, 2)
```

т.е.

```
12814433311
128144333112
```

если же создать код:

```
res = pow(12814433311, 2) - 21299881*pow(2776584, 2)

print(res)
```

то результат будет: 385

Comment: у меня получается 0

Comment: в онлайн компиляторе нормально 385 выходит, но у меня в pycharm нет, получается 0

Comment: у меня как раз в pycharm 2020.2 нормально выводится